# Using Select Field with ol li carousel Indicators

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, mean-stack, mean

\I'm using `Bootstrap Carousel` in Angular and I need to use a dropdown select option on `ol li` carousel indicators to select the slide number from there.
Here is my code:

```
 <ol class="carousel-indicators marg-top-sl">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleControls"></li>
  </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** disclamer, this question is about [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) carousel (not about a bootstrap-carousel). I don't remove the "answer" because I think that can help to someone, sorry

you're using ng-bootstrap carousel, so use the "methods" of the carousel. If you see the [API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api) you'll find the method `select`, so if your ngb-carousel is like (see that we put a "template reference variable"

```
<ngb-carousel #mycarousel *ngIf="images" [interval]="0">
  <ng-template ngbSlide id="id1">
   ...
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide id="id2">
   ...
  </ng-template>
  ...
</ngb-carousel>
```

We get the carousel using ViewChild()

```
  @ViewChild('mycarousel') carousel:any
```

Then, your select can be like

```
<select #select (change)="carousel.select(select.value)">
  <option value="id1">Forest</option>
  <option value="id2">Lake</option>
  <option value="id3">Mountains</option>
</select>
```

NOTE: You can use the `(slide)` method to makes that the select get the value of the slide using

```
<ngb-carousel #mycarousel *ngIf="images" [interval]="0" 
       (slide)="select.value=$event.current">
```

See that, in the API, when indicate a "Output" we can use `(name_of_the_output)="myfunction($event)"`, and the "$event" gets the value indicate in the API -in this case the API tell us that $event is an object of type NgbSlideEvent, so we can use the "properties" of NgbSlideEvent, in this case we use the property "current"

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zc7jno?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel-basic.ts)

Answer (score 0):

If we can use bootstrap carousel, the first is know how work. bootstrap carouse shoul has as active class one image, so we are going to has a variable indicate what indeex is selected (from 0 to images.length-1). So we can has

```
current:number=0;
```

Then ours images can be like

```
<div class="carousel-item active" [class.active]="current==0>
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item active" [class.active]="current==1>
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
...
```

An input or select with [(ngModel)]="current" should work

```
<select [(ngModel)]="current">
   <option value="0">1st image</option>
   <option value="1">2nd image</option>
   ....
</select>
```